# Cannot use "ON CONFLICT" with postgres updatable view and partial index

Tags: postgresql, view, upsert

I have an updatable view pointing to an underlying table that has a partial index. It looks something like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not exists foo (
    a INT,
    b INT,
    x INT,
    y INT,
    z BOOLEAN,
    CONSTRAINT x_or_y CHECK (
      (z and x is not null and y is null)
      or 
      (not z and x is null and y is not null)
    )
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux ON foo (x, a) WHERE z=TRUE;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uy ON foo (y, a) WHERE z=FALSE;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  foo_view AS 
    SELECT * FROM foo;
```

That is, for each row, `y` must be null if `z` is true; `x` must be null if `z` is false; and, only one of `x` and `y` may be not null. `(x, a)` and `(y, a)` must be unique. (Sorry if this is overly complicated. I'm translating from my real table that has a lot of other cruft.)

My problem comes when I want to update with `ON CONFLICT`. I believe I ought to be able to do this.

```sql
INSERT INTO foo_view(x, y, a, b, z)
  VALUES
  (5, null, 1, 2, true),
  (null, 5, 1, 2, false);
  

  
select * from foo_view;

INSERT INTO foo_view(x, y, a, b, z)
  VALUES
  (5, null, 1, 2, true)
ON CONFLICT (x, a) where z=true
  DO UPDATE
  set b = EXCLUDED.b;
```

But, I get the exception:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

I can insert into `foo` instead of `foo_view` with the same `ON CONFLICT` without error.

Here is a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cX2HXg91Q7yKoPeMBYzVLg/0

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match your question.

Comment: @jjanes - crap, must have forgotten to save. updated now. thanks!

Comment: The fiddle still doesn't match the the question - and it seems wrong. I suggest this test case to make your point clear (in the question *and* as fiddle): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8c1ed6052ac2365b825fa6d11ac1c413
Also, please provide your version of Postgres - for any such question!

Comment: The problem with updatable views aside, since `x` and `y` are mutually exclusive in your design, you might just merge both columns to something called `xy` and have a plain `UNIQUE` constraint on `(xy, z)` and both columns  `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 5):

After debugging through the PostgreSQL code, I'd say that there is a problem in the `infer_arbiter_indexes` function in `src/backend/optimizer/util/plancat.c`. It compares the index predicate to the `WHERE` condition in `ON CONFLICT`, but seems to ignore that they are on different objects.

I'm not sure if PostgreSQL is willing to consider that as a bug, but you might report it.